# Unable to set ArrayCollection equal to Result.Event

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm trying to set an array collection equal to a event.result that contains an array collection, but my array collection keeps coming up null. The event.result isn't empty because I can assign it as the dataprovider for a datagrid and that works (shows data correctly)

```
var ac = new ArrayCollection();
ac = event.result as ArrayCollection;
dgSomeDataGrid.dataProvider = event.result;
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `as` operator will return null if the object is not of the correct type.  Whatever event.result is, it isn't an `ArrayCollection`.  Do you know what it is?  One way to find out:

```
Alert.show(getQualifiedClassName(event.result))
```

If it is an `Array`, you can create a new collection:

```
var myData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(event.result);
```

More info would be nice.

Comment: You guys are right :). The return type from the WebOrb remote service was an array of objects, not an array collection. Changing it to: arrayPPCRList = event.result as Array solved the problem! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your result is `ArrayCollection`! This line:

```
dgSomeDataGrid.dataProvider = event.result;
```

hasn't any type related operations. Does this line work:

```
dgSomeDataGrid.dataProvider = event.result as ArrayCollection;
```

?

Place s breakpoint and check the real type of data.

Comment: What do you mean as no luck? What is exact type of `event.result` you've found when debugger stopped at your breakpoint?

Answer (score 1):

What is the result suppose to be? The 'as' operator will always return null if it can't cast whatever you're trying to cast.  My guess is that your result is returning something different (Array, Object, XML?) and you're trying to make it something that it's not.  Just use debug to check the type.